# Python fast api getting internal server error

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am new to python and fastapi, and was playing around it.

I wrote this code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

people = {
    "1": {
        "name": "abc", 
        "age": 27
    }, 
    "2": {
        "name": "xyz", 
        "age": 60
    }
}

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/people/")
def get_people(
    min_age: int=0, max_age: int=100
):
    results = [person for person in people.values() if person["age"] >= min_age and person["age"] <= max_age]
    return results


@app.get("/people/{person_id}")
def get_person(person_id: int): 
    return people[person_id]
```

but on calling `@app.get("/people/{person_id}")` I am getting 500 error with this as traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 407, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 235, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/Users/abcB/Desktop/fastapi-tutorial/./main.py", line 31, in get_person
    return people[person_id]
```

Can someone point me on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Which id do you provide ? Can you copy/paste a curl request to your server ?

Answer (score 1):

In your dictionary "people" you have declared the "id" (the keys) as strings.
However in the path operation of @app.get("/people/{person_id}") you have declared the person_id as an int. That's why the error occurs. Remember that pydantic uses these type declarations for data validation.

The correct thing would then be:

```
@app.get("/people/{person_id}")
def get_person(person_id: str): 
    return people[person_id]
```